# What is the <!> element in IE developer toolbar

Tags: internet-explorer, rendering

In noticed the <!> element in IE6 and 7 (haven't tested 8) developer toolbar. It appears to be an element created to hold the background image for one of my actual elements (the actual element is now a child of the <!> element according to IE)

Does anyone know what the <!> element is and why IE creates it to hold the background image (I have another virtually identical element next to the element that is now a child of the <!> element and that one does not need/gets an <!> element for the background image)

Actual Markup (simplified)

```
<div id='d1'>I have a background image</div>
<div id='d2'>So do I</div>
```

Markup as renderen by IE6 and 7

```
<!> <!-- now contains the background image for d1'-->
  div id='d1'>I no longer have a background image</div>
</!> <!-- or whatever the closing tag for <!> is -->
<div id='d2'>SI still have mine</div>
```

[image]

**EDIT**:
The actual site can be found [here](http://www.koningshofdoorn.nl/wordpress/). The actual markup is quite big and complex. (The element that is the problem is the #leftBar element, note that this has it's height determined by javascript)

This is all the CSS that descibes the element being wrapped in <!>

```
position:absolute;
left:0px; 
z-index:15;

width:15em; /* on update change: #contentWrapper:padding-left, #rondleiding:left */
height:100%;

overflow:visible;
background: url("http://somewhere/img.png") repeat #a99c89;
```

Also there are indeed javascript manipulations on the elements of the page, but these do not deal with the background image of the #leftBar element.

According to the W3C validator, the page is pretty much valid (some errors on images having rels).

<s>Also I'll be adding a bounty as I am now asking people to look at the actual website (which means digging into my shit).</s>(forget a question needs to be open two days for that)

Comment: That means stop using IE and its developer tool and switch to Mozilla and Firebug. In other words, I don't know what the heck it is.

Comment: It causes a rendering bug in IE :( otherwise I wouldn't be looking there either.

Comment: @Pim can you show the CSS that defines the background image? Also, are you 1000% sure you have valid HTML? This could be funny behaviour caused by a wrongly nested structure.

Comment: Let's have the *real* markup. A validator will probably find errors in it; IE will sometimes create weird broken DOM trees in response to invalid input. The other possibility is you've got script manipulating the nodes that accidentally treats a comment as an element: IE will let you read the `tagName` from a comment, giving `!`, which could confuse a script.

Comment: Interestingly, I am not getting `<!>` in my IE 8. It's `bottom` > `leftBar`. However, the background image doesn't seem to be showing up either (Edit: Ah, you mention 6 and 7...)

Comment: @Pekka Hmm, in my IE8 everything works fine :/ it's really IE 6 and 7 that are the problem (I don't have dev toolbar for IE8)

Comment: @Pekka, I fixed that, but indeed didn't change anything. Also I diddn't know that, thankyou, but I indeed don't get the <!> containing element in IE8 either. Edit: just noticed you edited your comment.

Comment: @Pim the validator is complaining about "bogus comments": `<![if gte IE 8]>` maybe make them real comments.

Comment: @Pim then you have an empty comment above the bottom div: `<!-- -->` maybe also remove, just in case

Comment: Unrelated, why are you loading all the JavaScript in the `body` element? That could and should all go into the `head`, shouldn't it?

Comment: @Pekka, the bogus comments are IE's "conditional comments that aren't really comments so other browsers execute them and certain versions of IE do not", I removed them but it didn;t fix anything (I also removed the rel attributes on the images so the page passes the validator, but that didn't fix anything either). The empty comment is there to fix in IE<7 bug where divs have a minimum height of roughly the line-height (removing it doesn't help)). And the scripting loading in the body is so the content loads first, but i'll try moving it to the head.

Comment: @Pekka, moving scripts to head didn't help either :(

Comment: @Pim I'm aware they were conditional comments, but the IE8 ones weren't correct: The correct form is `<!--[if gte IE 8]> ... <![endif]-->` (The IE7 ones below were okay.) But if removing them didn't help, then that wasn't the problem. Really strange!

Comment: @Pim moving the scripts to the head was more a general thing, not aimed at the problem. It should be fine loading them there.

Comment: @Pekka, yeah I know, just thought that maybe it could change something. Also about the conditional comments thing, that's weird, I copied the syntax from msdn: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537512(VS.85).aspx anyway, thanks for your help! (If you have any other ideas I'd love to hear them)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's being caused by a bug in the ie7/ie8.js script. I haven't worked out how yet... not much fun to debug as that library is such a maze of twisty little features. Do you really need to include it? If there is one specific behaviour you want to fix it may be better to just address that separately. I've never really trusted these enormous attempt-to-fix-everything-at-once scripts.

So instead I'll point out that you seem to be loading jQuery twice (once from Google, once from your own site with the wrong MIME type), and you've got this validation problem (the rest of the doc seems OK):

```
<![if gte IE 8]>
    ...
<![endif]>
```

It is unfortunate that MSDN is still handing out this invalid conditional comment syntax, since it's easy to have a downlevel-revealed conditional comment that's also valid:

```
<!--[if gte IE 8]><!-->
    ...
<!--<![endif]-->
```

Comment: Thanks, It was indeed the ie8.js script (iefix/ie7.js is a script of my own which fixes some specific issues in this site). Thanks for your help! To bad that the ie8 script causes this as I really like the idea of the script (although in the end, it turned out that removing it only caused one minor float position bug). Thank you very much! And I too think it's very weird that msdn shows the invalid syntax when IE also understands the valid syntax :/

Answer (score -1):

Is it possible the real (not simplified) markup contains a syntax error? I've seen IE Dev Toolbar completely freak out on things as simple as missing a closing `"` on an attribute.

Comment: This should be a comment really, there is already speculation to that effect... Also, the live URL is now up